# Push notification issue in Oreo 8.0

Tags: android, push-notification, android-pendingintent, android-8.0-oreo, google-pixel

After updating the app to 8.1 the notification was not shown and I fixed it. Now, pending intent is not working as expected.

After receiving the notification, I am not able to navigate to the app if it is in background and if it is closed it is not launching.

```
private void sendNotify(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Constants.NOTIFY);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    int uniqueId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // Creates the PendingIntent
        PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this,
                        0,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );

        String channelID = "com.myapp.ind.push.ServiceListener";// The id of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, "MyApp", importance);
        // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
        Notification notification = getNotificationBuilder(messageBody, notifyPendingIntent, defaultSoundUri)
                .setChannelId(channelID)
                .build();

        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
            notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, notification);
        }
    } else if (notificationManager != null) {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            uniqueId /* Request code */,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = getNotificationBuilder(messageBody, pendingIntent, defaultSoundUri);
        notificationManager.notify(uniqueId /* ID of notification */,
                notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder(String messageBody, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Uri defaultSoundUri) {
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_title))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

**Edit:**

On click of notification it was working fine till 6.0. After updating to 8.0 it is not working in Google Pixel devices. It is not opening the app or bringing the app to foreground.

Comment: try adding `setAction(...pendingIntent);` to notificationBuilder

Comment: I don't want any UI action button in notification. On click of the notification it should open the app

Comment: Implicit broadcasts no longer work for manifest-registered Receivers, as of Oreo (with some exceptions for certain system broadcasts). Change the `Intent` to an explicit `Intent`; i.e., one that targets your specific Receiver class - e.g., `Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourReceiver.class);`. Also, you have `PendingIntent.getActivity()` instead of `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` in the `if` block. Mistype?

Comment: As part of my implementation, I am not able to add the Result.class explicitly. But the same worked till targetedVersion 23

Comment: Actually, that restriction should only take effect when you target 26 or above (which will soon be required for Play Store apps, btw). I thought I'd edited that into my comment, but it didn't commit, apparently. Anyway, why can't you specify your Receiver class?

Comment: Ya Thanks @Mike. It helped me. I have created a Receiver and launched the activity from there. Create the comment as answer, I will accept it

Comment: @AbishR can you show post the solution to the community ...so that others can take reference from it..

Answer (score 4):

Create a Receiver class like below. And register that is manifest file.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction() != null
            && intent.getAction().equals("My Call")) {
            Intent startIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
            context.startActivity(startIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

The below code from the Notification class after receiving the notification.

```
private void sendNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Receiver.class);
    intent.setAction("My Call");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    int uniqueId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            uniqueId /* Request code */,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && notificationManager != null) {
        String channelID = "Your Channel ID";// The id of the channel.
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelID, "My_Name", importance);
        // Create a notification and set the notification channel.
        Notification notification = getNotificationBuilder(messageBody, pendingIntent, defaultSoundUri)
                .setChannelId(channelID)
                .build();

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        notificationManager.notify(uniqueId, notification);
    } else if (notificationManager != null) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = getNotificationBuilder();
        notificationManager.notify(uniqueId /* ID of notification */,
                notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder getNotificationBuilder() {
    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(image)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

Now I am receiving the notification in all the device. Previously also I received but not displayed in status bar because of Channel implementation in Oreo devices. Now working perfectly.