# Android Push notification : Few devices (like vivo)when app is not in running state, all notifications get delivered all together when app is reopened

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When the app is not running (background/foreground), in few devices FCM push notifications get delivered.

While in few phones (like Vivo models) for this app state, all notifications get delivered all together when the app is reopened.

I have used `BroadcastReceiver` with `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method and followed below helpful links,

1. [Push notification issue in Oreo 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645550/push-notification-issue-in-oreo-8-0/59945853?noredirect=1#comment106012576_59945853)
2. [Some Oreo devices are not getting Push Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849445/some-oreo-devices-are-not-getting-push-notification/52943903#52943903)

Still for Vivo models I received all notifications only when app is reopened.Ideally though app is not running in background/foreground, app should receive all notifications. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show the payload you are sending through FCM? Are you using a data-only notification or do you have a notification section too?

Comment: Hi Derryl, I am using data-only notification (onMessageReceived()-remoteMessage.data ).. Payload is as inside remoteMessage.data.get("message")
=
{"image_big_URL":"","new_rss_url":"","hub_url":"","ios_new_rss_url":"","Title":"","RssUrl":"","save_opt":"0","CREATION_DATE2":"","live_tv_channel_name":"","message":"Message","collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","SharingUrl":"","web_url":"","delay_while_idle":true,"post_type":"","category":"","msg_id":"239856","lang":"eng"}.   If you have any suggestions/solutions please let me know. Thanks.